# R: how to add row name to a data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe

here is what I got

```
     id nobs
[1,]  2 1041
[2,]  4  474
[3,]  8  192
[4,] 10  148
[5,] 12   96
```

and I want to make it like this

```
  id nobs
1  2 1041
2  4  474
3  8  192
4 10  148
5 12   96
```

what would I do?

Comment: Are you sure you have a data frame there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually given your data structure and the desire to convert matrix to data frame, you could do below which is an one-stone-two-birds. Otherwise you could change row names as suggested by @akrun.

```
# your matrix
M <- structure(1:10, .Dim = c(5L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("id", 
"nobs")))

# convert to data frame
M <- as.data.frame(M)
M
#   id nobs
# 1  1    6
# 2  2    7
# 3  3    8
# 4  4    9
# 5  5   10
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `row.names`.  Not sure if you want to convert `matrix` to `data.frame`.

```
row.names(data) <- 1:nrow(data)
data
#  id nobs
#1  2 1041
#2  4  474
#3  8  192
#4 10  148
#5 12   96
```

Comment: thank you! I do want to convert matrix to data.frame, and I did it by myself